# PyTorch - How to set Activation Rules of neurons to increase efficiency of Neural Network?

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to make a Back Propagation Neural Network with PyTorch. I can successfully execute and test its accuracy, but it doesn't work very efficiently. Now, I'm supposed to increase its efficiency by setting different activation rules for neurons, so that those neurons that don't contribute to the final output get excluded (pruned) from the computations, thereby increasing the time and accuracy.

My code looks like this (extracted snippets) -

```
# Hyper Parameters
input_size = 20
hidden_size = 50
num_classes =130
num_epochs = 500
batch_size = 5
learning_rate = 0.1

# normalise input data
for column in data:
# the last column is target
if column != data.shape[1] - 1:
    data[column] = data.loc[:, [column]].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())

# randomly split data into training set (80%) and testing set (20%)
msk = np.random.rand(len(data)) < 0.8
train_data = data[msk]
test_data = data[~msk]

# define train dataset and a data loader
train_dataset = DataFrameDataset(df=train_data)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Neural Network
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
net = Net(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes)

# train the model by batch
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for step, (batch_x, batch_y) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # convert torch tensor to Variable
        X = Variable(batch_x)
        Y = Variable(batch_y.long())

        # Forward + Backward + Optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # zero the gradient buffer
        outputs = net(X)
        loss = criterion(outputs, Y)
        all_losses.append(loss.data[0])
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if epoch % 50 == 0:
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            # calculate and print accuracy
            total = predicted.size(0)
            correct = predicted.data.numpy() == Y.data.numpy()

            print('Epoch [%d/%d], Step [%d/%d], Loss: %.4f, Accuracy: %.2f %%' % (epoch + 1, num_epochs, step + 1, len(train_data) // batch_size + 1, loss.data[0], 100 * sum(correct)/total))
```

Can someone tell me how to do that in PyTorch as I'm very new to PyTorch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that question is supposed to be on stackoverflow, but I will give you a hint anyway. You are working with a sigmoid activation function at the moment, the gradient of which vanishes if the input value is too large to small. A commonly used approach is to use the ReLU activation function (stands for rectified linear unit).

ReLU(x) is the identity for the positive domain and 0 for the negative domain, in Python that would be written as follows:

```
def ReLU(x):
    if(x > 0):
        return x
    else:
        return 0
```

It should be readily available in PyTorch

Comment: Thanks! That works to increase the accuracy a bit. However, the execution stops at Epochs 450/500 for some reason. But, this is not the exact thing that I was looking for to increase my accuracy.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question then ;)

Comment: Does that look a bit better now?

Comment: Got it, what you mean goes by the name of pruning, there is even a PyTorch implementation of one approach around: https://jacobgil.github.io/deeplearning/pruning-deep-learning

Comment: Yeah, already seen this one! :) Sadly, this one deals with Convolution NN which isn't what I need. Any ideas on how to implement the same in Neural Nets.

Comment: Reduce the spatial dimensions both to 1 and take the channels as the neurons in your architecture and you are there. A NN is like 1x1 convolutions over an image with size 1x1